# Asking git to ignore a folder that other people check code into

Tags: git, git-sparse-checkout

I'm working on a huge, sprawling, corporate git repo that lots of other people check code into. There are huge folders in it that are of no interest to me at all. I don't read or write code there, and I don't need that code to work on my code.

These folders have a lot of files and also submodules inside of them, and they're slowing down my Git tools.

Is it possible to tell Git: Do not check out folder "foo" at all, nor any of the subfolders and files inside of it? I want to be able to use Git freely for making new commits of files outside of "foo".

Comment: See sparse checkout, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout. Note that the metadata of the unchecked-out folders still  exist and are transferable.